# How to display classic Google Sites search box query in home page?

Tags: google-apps-script

**I need to pass the contents** of the Google Sites search box text to the main or home page. So far I have tried the following...

**Code.gs:**

```
function doGet(e) {
var word = e.parameter.q;
var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Index");
  return template
    .evaluate()
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function display() {
    return word;
}
```

**Index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <?!= display(); ?>
<base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I published the script and deployed it as a web app, and embedded the script in the home page successfully. Also, the site search was properly configured to include the ***Google Search Appliance Url*** in ***Additional Search Providers***.

The main problem is that the script opens a new page when trying to display the word entered to the search box. Please help me so the search box text is displayed directly in the home page, without opening an extra HTML output.

¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶

The following script gets the search box input in site https://sites.google.com/site/ei38f7s783hu2hhs and displays it in an HTML output:

**Code.gs:**

```
function doGet(e) {
  var word = e.parameter.q; // this gets the search box input
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(word);
}
```

**Index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <?!= display(); ?>
<base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The idea is to write the search box text **directly** to the home page, and not to an external HTML output. So I added an **`Index`** file, like in the previous code, to see if the results would display in home page, but it doesn't work.

The script has been **Deployed as a web app** (in this case, the query is the word **north**)
→ https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxeaPOX52qr8kYzD8jXfI9vzsWpxI49AHajaJx0qSSmastoMHle/exec?q=north

Please let me know if there is need of further explanation.

¶¶¶¶¶ **How to configure the site search** ¶¶¶¶¶

After publishing the script as a web app the site search has to be configured:

In your Google Site:

- Go to the gear wheel
- Select **Manage site**
- Go to **Configure search**
- Click on **Advanced**
- Click on button **Add provider**
- In Type select **Google Search Appliance**
- Fill the **Name** (→ text for the new search button)
- Add *Google Search Appliance Url* (from published script)
- Click OK

This way, the newly published script can get the search box values directly by means of **`doGet(e)`** and **`e.parameter.q`**.

Comment: I think that in your script, an error occurs because `word` of `display()` is not declared. How about this? And about `embedded the script in the home page`, if you can do, can you provide the HTML for embedding it? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Thanks for answering **Tanaike**. I added some explanation to the former question after ¶. Please let me know if there is need of more specifications.

Comment: Thank you for adding the information. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. I apologize for this. Can you provide the method for putting the text input box?

Comment: Please see the additions for how to configure site search.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I posted an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Please wait a bit. I'm testing the two options to see what's the result. There is a link to better understand the issue, kindly visit it. → https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/learn-by-example/other-examples/advanced-search-on-google-sites

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your replying. Because UI Service has already been deprecated. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/ui-service)

Comment: This is solved right?

Comment: Not yet TheMaster

Answer (score 1):

- You want to input a value to the text input box and want to put the value retrieved from Google Apps Script side to the page without moving the page.

I could understand like above. If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

### Issue and workaround:

From your updated question, I could understand that you are using the Google site of classic type. In this case, I think that Class SitesApp can be still used. By using this, the result value can be put to the page like below.

```
function doGet(e) {
    var word = e.parameter.q;

    var site = SitesApp.getSite("###");
    site.getChildren()[0].setHtmlContent(word);

    var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Index");
      return template
        .evaluate()
        .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

But unfortunately, the page cannot be automatically refreshed and the opened tag of Web Apps cannot be closed. So I would like to propose the following workaround.

In this workaround, the Google site of the current type is used. And Web Apps is embedded to the page. The sample script of this workaround is as follows.

### Usage

#### 1. Prepare sample script:

Please put the following scripts to the GAS project and deploy Web Apps as new version as "Execute the app as:" of "Me" and "Who has access to the app:" of "Anyone, even anonymous". And please copy the URL of Web Apps.

Google Apps Script: `Code.gs`

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index");
}

function myFunction(e) {
  return "Received value is " + e;
}
```

HTML&Javascript: `index.html`

```
<input type="text" id="text" name="text">
<input type="button" value="ok" onclick="sample()">
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
function sample() {
  const t = document.getElementById("text").value;
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(e => {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = e;
  }).myFunction(t);
}
</script>
```

#### 2. Create new site with current type:

1. Create new site with the current type.
2. Click "Embed" icon at the left side.

   - At "By URL", please input the URL of Web Apps.
   - Click "Insert" button.
3. As testing the site, please click "Preview" at the top.

By this, Web Apps is run and you can see the text box. When you put a value of "sample" and "ok" button, you can see "Received value is sample" which was returned from Web Apps without opening new tab.

### Note:

- When you modified the script of Web Apps, please redeploy Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected. Please be careful this.

### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Google site](https://sites.google.com/new)

Comment: Thanks for your patience Tanaike. Your last solution is good in case of creating a custom search box and embedding the URL of the web app. But the original question was about using the default Google Sites search box. It's unfortunate the UI is deprecated.

Comment: @Julio C. P. Thank you for replying. And also, at the current Google site, the page can be dynamically refreshed by Web Apps. If my answer is incomplete for your goal, please tell me. I would like to think of the modification.

Comment: So, there is a way to do this in new Google Sites? Can you elaborate on this please?

Comment: @Julio C. P. Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. In my answer, the current Google site is used and I have explained about it. In order to create new Google site, please access to https://sites.google.com/new  and create it. The installation flow can be seen at my answer.

Comment: Very useful answer ▲.